# Can you place widgets relatively in tKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Is there a way to position input boxes and such relatively to other elements in tKinter?

Comment: `.place` is only relative to the parent widget. Look at `.pack`/`.grid`.

Comment: yes. `pack` lets you put widgets above, below, or to the side of other widgets, as does `place`. `grid` also allows it by virtue of defining a grid. We need more details to know exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) tutorial from TkDocs.

Here's what I do, briefly:

```
# Widgets
namelabel = tk.Label(self, text="Text") # Widget
namelabel.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10) # Place with grid

quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.destroy)
quit_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5) # See how you can set up a series of rows/columns?

# Configure rows/columns
self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

This is done in the context of object-oriented programming (self). I find OOP is great for creating windows/functions that interact with other windows/functions, but if you have a simple single frame you may not need it.